How Can I Add a Payment to a Pledge?
Maybe I am being fick, but on the record of a contact with an overdue pledge payment, a warning pops up that a payment is overdue with a link to a screen where I can add the payment to the pledge.
But how can I get to that same input screen when the payment isn't overdue and just add a payment? I can't seem to find any way of navigating to the same screen.
There are no end of ways of navigating to screens for adding new pledges, which seems to be far less likely to be needed than adding payments to an existing pledge.
How do I just add a payment?

I have found the answer to my question. The little arrow to the left which says "show payments" when you hover, actually shows due payments and allows you to enter a payment against the relevant date.
